# Get records that expire in 1 month

Tags: mysql

I have a documents table, documents may or may not have expiry dates.

I need to find all documents that expire in 1 month

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ph_document` d
    LEFT JOIN `ph_user` u ON d.user_id = u.user_id 
        WHERE `notification_one_month` = 0 
            AND `document_expiry` != 0  
            AND `document_expiry` >= NOW()
            AND `document_expiry` <= DATEADD(m,-1,NOW)
```

Sadly the date columns in this table are INT holding Unix Epoch timestamps and not actually `DATE` or `DATETIME` so I'm a little lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a proper conversion in datatime and the use a between now() a month

```
SELECT * FROM `ph_document` d
LEFT JOIN `ph_user` u ON d.user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE `notification_one_month` = 0 
        AND `document_expiry` != 0  
        AND from_unixtime(`document_expiry`) BETWEEN  NOW()  
                AND  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```